# Trouble getting old message board software to work on new host

Tags: php, apache

I recently moved my entire site to a new host. I had only minor issues getting my SMF board to work on the new host but I'm afraid I've reached my knowledge limit on getting my old, dusty Ikonboard (which uses a Berekely DB) to work. It's not a board we currently use but more of an archive.

In theory all I should've had to do was edit the server settings in a file called Boardinfo.cgi, which I did. I was still getting errors when I tried to access the board. So I contacted my new host and asked them if there was anything else they could think of that I needed to do to get it running. Their response was, in part:

> It appears there are some issue with the version/software you are
>   trying to use. The environment Ikonboard is trying use Apache/1.3.27
>   (Unix) while the server currently uses Apache/2.2.25 (Unix).
>
> Also when getting visiting
>   [http://OURSITE.com/cgi-bin/ikonboard.cgi] we are getting errors
>   for the PHP handler. We are not sure if Ikonboard is trying to use
>   "nobody" or another user to run. Which ever it is not correctly set up
>   for suPHP which is the current PHP handler.
>
> As in [http://OURSITE.com/Install_Guide.html] we have chmod the
>   files to 755 and that is allowing the file to oad, but not
>   successfully run the code inside.
>
> We have added in a php.ini to the public_html folder that will allow
>   you to adjust any php setting that may require it to run. However
>   looking into the code does fall out of the realms of our support. You
>   may try contacting Ikonboard to see if they can shed some light on
>   this issue.

I'm primarily a web/graphic designer and not a programmer so most of this doesn't make much sense to me (though I've had some success doing php edits on sites in the past). I did pose the question on the Ikonboard message boards but since Ikonboard is pretty much dead, their support boards are populated by a bunch of tumbleweeds blowing by. I'm willing to throw money at this issue, if it can be solved, but I thought I'd ask here before I do that.

Any ideas would be very much appreciated!